# Two apparently different evaluations of $\int \frac{x-1}{9x^2-18x+17}dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

> Evaluate the indefinite integral $$\int \frac{x-1}{9x^2-18x+17} \, dx .$$

This is an exercise from a book I'm studying. It gives the answer as: 
$$\ln(9x^2 -18x+17)^\frac{1}{18} +C .$$
This is an easy integral. You just notice that the numerator is the derivative of the denominator.

But I didn't notice exactly that at first, so I solved it in a slightly different way. I did:
$$\int \frac{x-1}{9x^2-18x+17}\, dx=\frac{1}{18}\int \frac{x-1}{\frac{x^2}{2}-x+\frac{17}{18}}\, dx$$ so $$z=\frac{x^2}{2}-x+\frac{17}{18}, \quad \frac{dz}{dx}=x-1 $$
I find the answer in the usual way as: $$\frac{1}{18} \int\frac{1}{z} dz= \frac{1}{18}\ln\left(\frac{x^2}{2}-x+\frac{17}{18}\right)+C , $$
which is (I believe) different from the answer the book gives, because the arguments of $ln$ are different. What is the problem here? Where am I wrong?

Comment: pull an $1/18$ out of the logarithm and put in the constant of integration. then both answers look the same.

Comment: $$\int \frac{x-1}{9x^2-18x+17}dx=\dfrac{1}{18}\log(9x^{2}-18x+17)+Cst$$

Comment: $$\frac{1}{18}\ln\left(\frac{x^2}{2}-x+\frac{17}{18}\right)=\frac{1}{18}\left( \ln\left(9x^2-18x+17\right)-\ln(18)\right)$$

$$=\ln\left(\left(9x^2-18x+17\right)^{\frac{1}{18}}\right)-\frac{\ln(18)}{18}$$

$-\frac{\ln(18)}{18}$ is a constant.

Comment: @user236182 well exactly. Your answer is different from the one the book gives. This is what i found too. Are you saying that $-\frac{ln(18)}{18}$ is our constant of integration?

Comment: @RestlessC0bra The answers are both correct, because $\frac{1}{18}\ln\left(\frac{x^2}{2}-x+\frac{17}{18}\right)$ and $\ln\left(\left(9x^2-18x+17\right)^{\frac{1}{18}}\right)$ differ only by a constant (namely $-\frac{\ln(18)}{18}$).

Comment: @RestlessC0bra The integral of a function is the set of all antiderivatives. All antiderivatives of any function are different by a constant (if $f'(x)-f'(y)=0$, then $f(x)-f(y)$ is a constant), and remember the derivative of a constant is $0$, so it doesn't matter if you add a constant to an antiderivative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite appearances to the contrary, there's no problem here: The two expressions actually differ by a constant, but this equivalence is buried in a few special identities involving the logarithm function, namely $$\log (ab) = \log a + \log b$$ and $\log (a^b) = b \log a$ (both for appropriate $a, b$).

More specifically, note that
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{18} \log \left(\frac{x^2}{2} - x + \frac{17}{18}\right) + \color{#0000ff}{\frac{1}{18} \log 18}
&= \frac{1}{18}\log\left[\left(\frac{x^2}{2} - x + \frac{17}{18}\right) (18)\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{18} \log\left(9x^2 - x + \frac{17}{18}\right) \\
&= \log\left[\left(9x^2 - x + \frac{17}{18}\right)^{\frac{1}{18}}\right] .
\end{align}
By absorbing the constant $\color{#0000ff}{\frac{1}{18} \log 18}$ into $C$, we see that your general antiderivative and the one the text gives, regarded as families of functions (all equal up to addition of a constant), are actually the same.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \frac{x-1}{9x^2-18x+17}dx=\dfrac{1}{18}\log(9x^{2}-18x+17)+Cst$$

indeed,

- Substitute $u=9x^2-18x+17$ and $du=(18x-18)dx$

\begin{align}
\int \frac{x-1}{9x^2-18x+17}dx&=\dfrac{1}{18}\int \dfrac{1}{u}du\\
&=\dfrac{1}{18}\log(u)+Cst
\end{align}

- Substitute back for $u=9x^2-18x+17$:
  \begin{align}
  \int \frac{x-1}{9x^2-18x+17}dx&=\dfrac{1}{18}\log(u)+Cst\\
  &=\dfrac{1}{18}\log(9x^2-18x+17 )+Cst
  \end{align}